# Adding dropdown select meta box to custom post type - seems restAPI is interfering

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-field, metabox

I have a custom post type, call it `topic`. It is from BBPress, but this isn't a BBPress question.

I also have a post type `lessontopic`.

I added a meta box to BBPress so that I can choose an associated Lesson Topic for the Forum Topic when I am in the BBPress Topic backend editor, and that save that as `post meta data`.

Here is what I did:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'ld_bbpress_display_ldtopic_selector');

function ld_bbpress_display_ldtopic_selector() {
    add_meta_box( 'ld_bbpress_ldtopic_selector', __( 'LearnDash bbPress Settings', 'learndash-bbpress' ), 'ld_bbpress_display_topic_selector_callback', 'topic', 'advanced', 'high' );
}

function ld_bbpress_display_topic_selector_callback() {
   My call back stuff
}

add_action( 'save_post_topic', 'ld_save_associated_ldtopic',10,1);
function ld_save_associated_ldtopic($topic_id){
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['ld_bbpress_nonce_ldtopic'], 'ld_bbpress_meta_box_ldtopic' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    my save stuff
}
```

Now everything looks ok in backend. But if I choose a lesson topic from my meta dropdown, and hit update, and step through in my debugger, I see that the update is performed in

`wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php`

This has to do with the fact that for a custom block I made that enables me to select forum topics, I had to enable BBPress topics to be seen in restAPI, and that mysteriously causes backend editor to hit the restAPI endpoint for updates. I did that restAPI enabling via

```
add_filter( 'bbp_register_topic_post_type', 'enable_restAPI_bbpress_topics', 10,1);
function enable_restAPI_bbpress_topics ($args) {
    $args['show_in_rest'] = true;
    $args['supports'] = array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' );
    return $args;
}
```

But I don't understand: why does the mere act of checking off that a post type is visible to restAPI cause wordpress's backend editor to go into a completely different mode of operation? I mean, we are talking about backend. If I enable restAPI, I can see how that should facilitate headless CMS, etc, but why on earth does it so radically alter how Wordpress deals with backend post editing?

Somehow, this is resulting in my save hook `ld_save_associated_ldtopic` not seeing the `$_POST` array and therefore not seeing nonce data.

Really quite peculiar. I feel like I am breaking some rule and it is biting me, but not sure what I need to do to get my meta box to work in this fashion.

Ideas?

thanks,
Brian

Comment: with the new editor gutenberg, saving a post is done with the REST API. but it always a POST request then you should read data chosen by the user on the action `save_post_topic`. look what append with the Network Monitor of your browser. If you use Firefox, you can show it with Ctrl + Shift + E
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

Comment: The thing is, when I compare updates in different post types, class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php update_post is not always called. In my case it is being called, and something about that is making it such that $_POST is not even set when program flow gets to my save hook. I think the show_in_rest parameter adds extra constraints and I need to somehow allow my meta box save hook to receive a $_POST variable. Somewhere along the way the rest controller is unsetting $_POST...

Comment: oh, I just seen on my tests that there is 2 request when saving. first : POST to REST API with the only content ($_POST is empty here). and the second : POST to post.php, there $_POST contains boxes values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't understand: why does the mere act of checking off that a
>   post type is visible to restAPI cause wordpress's backend editor to go
>   into a completely different mode of operation?

WordPress 5.0 introduced the [Block Editor](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/). This is an entirely new post editing screen and method of editing posts. It works by using the REST API. So if you have a post type that is not available in the REST API, it will fall back to the old "Classic" editor, and continue to function as it used to.

If the post type *is* enabled in the REST API, then unless otherwise specified (such as by using the [`use_block_editor_for_post_type`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/use_block_editor_for_post_type/) filter), the Block Editor will be used instead.

Custom meta boxes created using `add_meta_box` should continue to work in the block editor, but they have to be handled differently for compatibility with the Block Editor. How this works is documented [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/backward-compatibility/meta-box/).

But there should be no issue with `$_POST` being seen inside the `save_post` or `save_post_topic` hook. If you're attempting to debug, it's likely that you're looking at the wrong request. Most changes in the editor will be sent to the REST API endpoint, and handled by that, but meta boxes will be posted as a separate request to `/wp-admin/post.php`, where the normal actions will fire. The only difference being that this now happens in the background.

Comment: When I set a breakpoint on my save_post_topic hook there is no $_POST variable. I did a test in another post type that also has a custom meta box, and it did not trigger the class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php update_post method (whereas in my case this method is called), and it had $_POST available in its save_post_{$posttype} hook. Really quite perplexing.

Comment: I've explained why the REST API will be called for one post type but not another. It's quite straightfoward. Regarding `save_post`, as I mentioned in my answer, two separate requests are going to be fired  when the post is updated. Once for the REST API, and once for the meta boxes. `save_post_topic` _will fire for both of these_, but `$_POST` will not exist for the REST API request. Your debugging needs to account for the fact that `save_post` runs multiple times per update.

Comment: Ahhh, ok, totally see what you mean. I see $_POST in 2nd call to the save hook. Still not understanding why one post type's update triggers the rest controller's update_post method and the other doesn't. That oddity had me thinking I had a restAPI nuance... Thanks again

Comment: Are both post types enabled for the REST API?

Comment: The other one isn't, but it looks like it uses classic editor.

Comment: Well there you go, as I described in my answer the new editor uses the REST API, and the Classic Editor doesn't.